# Get the day of the week from a date using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I now it has been aswer before, the problem is that I get the date from an input is not the current date.

I need to get the day of the week. Currently I get the date with this format :

```
11/09/2013
```

But I want it like:

```
Saturday/02/2013.
```

I'm using datepicker to show the calendar, so it could be some solution that would help me using the same plugin.

Comment: Can you explain how 11/09/2013 translates to Saturday/02/2013?

Comment: Is an example, I just need the day on string.

Comment: You shouldn't need jQuery for this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var date = new Date();
var weekdays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

var weekday = weekdays[date.getDay()];
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var year = date.getYear();
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm using the value of a variable, It works perfect when I use new Date, but how to do it whit a varible that I get from the datepicker?

Comment: You can get a date from your datepicker with some kind of date parser.  This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse shows a nice simple date parsing function for dates in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`.  you should be able to customize that for the format you get back from the date picker.  You should also check, some datepicker libraries have a 'getDate' kind of method that should give you the date as a Javascript Date.